# How and where to create Yii2 Access Rules using mdmsoft/yii2-admin

Tags: php, authentication, frameworks, rbac, yii2-rbac

Hi developers I am new to YII , I have installed the YII2 framework and want a RBAC I have installed mdmsoft/yii2-admin module , but I do not know how to create RULE class, where to create it and then how to use. When I create a role in admin section it say , enter a Class Name. I don't know how to create and use the RULE feature of YII. I have attached the screen shot.[image]

Comment: This video tutorial about yii2-admin module will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLb8YATO-HU&t=1s

Comment: okay thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Advanced template here are the steps;

1. Create a directory under `frontend` and rename it `rbac`
2. Create a file under this new directory, say, `AuthorRule.php`. Here is a sample file given in the official docs;

> ```
> namespace app\rbac;
>
>
> use yii\rbac\Rule;
> use app\models\Post;
>
> /**
>  * Checks if authorID matches user passed via params
>  */
> class AuthorRule extends Rule
> {
>     public $name = 'isAuthor';
>
>     /**
>      * @param string|int $user the user ID.
>      * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
>      * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
>      * @return bool a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
>      */
>     public function execute($user, $item, $params)
>     {
>         return isset($params['post']) ? $params['post']->createdBy == $user : false;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Next step is to navigate to `http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=admin/rule` and create a new rule with class name `\app\rbac\AuthorRule`
4. Finally you can add the new rule to `roles` and `permissions` depending on your needs.

You can read the official docs for more information on rules; [the official docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-rules).